# Adding three or more XMLLISTCollections in Flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex

I have an XML structure :

```
<xml>
  <a>
   <name>A</name>
   <schl>AB</schl>
   </a>
  <a>
   <name>B</name>
<schl>BC</schl>
  </a>
  <b>
   <name>C</name>
   <schl>CD</schl>
   </b>
    <c>
     <name>D</name>
      <schl>DE</schl>
   </c>
</xml>
```

now, I need an XMLListCollection variable that should contain only the name elements of element a, b and c..
so, I tried something like this :

```
var combXml:XMLListCollection  = new XMLListCollection();
combXml.addItem(new XMLListCollection(xml.a.name);
combXml.addItem(new XMLListCollection(xml.b.name);
combXml.addItem(new XMLListCollection(xml.c.name);
```

and then pass it to a dataprovider..

```
treeDP.dataProvider = combXml;
```

but I got an error.

Does anyone knows how to combine these elements into the combXml?

Comment: Why do you need an XMLListCollection variable that only contains the name?  What error did you get?  What are you trying to accomplish?  It is a bit odd that your XML has different roots (a, b, c) that have identical children.

Comment: I agree with @www.Flextras.com.  Idomatically, this XML is a mess.  Having different node names (a,b,c) causes a real mess.  If a,b,c were just person nodes, you'd be able to call `xml.person.name` which would give you an XMLList of ["A", "B", "C"].  Further, you are creating a 2-dimentional XMLListCollection.  Do you really want that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Directly one XML source for 3 ComboBoxes as

```
<mx:ComboBox id="a" dataProvider="{myXml.a}" labelField="name"/>
<mx:ComboBox id="b" dataProvider="{myXml.b}" labelField="name"/>
<mx:ComboBox id="c" dataProvider="{myXml.c}" labelField="name"/>
```

**myXml** is a xml varaiabe and **myXml.a** returns **XmlList** object

equals to

```
var axList:XMLList = myXml.a;
```

EDITED: To get all elements[a,b,c] **name** you should use it as

```
<mx:ComboBox id="d" dataProvider="{XML(myXml).elements('*').name}" labelField="name"/>
```

Hopes that helps

Comment: @www.Flextras.com, my xml contains subnodes a,b,c and d. i want to get the name element of each of those subnotes and pass them into a dataProvider.. so, letz assume i had only one subnode a, then it would be easy to do sth like this: var combXml:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection(a.name);

Comment: @www.Flextras.com, my xml contains subnodes a,b,c and d. i want to get the name element of each of those subnotes and pass them into a dataProvider.. so, letz assume i had only one subnode a, then it would be easy to do sth like this: var combXml:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection(a.name); and then pass the combXml to a dataprovider..in the real xml, the node was an XMLList because a has a subnode variable which has the name elements..so, the real node would be something:combXml:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection(a.variable.name); that was easy but now, i want to get that b also.

Comment: @ henry joseph plz check edited contents, getting name element of all (a, b, c) elemants

Comment: @imran, what i wanted to get was collect the XMLListCollection of the nodes in one container and pass that container to the dataProvider. so, it is different from what you mean.

Comment: EDIT part is doing same. use can do it like that var xList:XMLList = XML(myXml).elements('*').name; xCol:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection(xList);

Comment: hi guys, i finally solved this problem..i just used an array to store the two XMLListCollection and pass the arrayCollection to a dataProvider..

Comment: Did you checked "elements('*')"